# VPC "fromLookup" results in all Private Subnets and no Public Subnets

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Using CDK v1.1.0 I'm trying to create an internet-facing Application Load Balancer.

When I call `ec2.vpc.fromLookup` using my `vpcId`, I get all my subnets, but all of them are marked as `PRIVATE` Subnets. Due to this I get an error that there are no Public Subnets Available.

If I try using `ec2.vpc.fromVpcAttributes` using my `vpcId`, `availabilityZones` and `SubnetIDs`, I get the error "Cannot read property 'selectSubnets' of undefined".

Route Table of My Subnets: 
Within the Subnets, my RouteTable has two Routes:

- Destination: 10.140.0.0/16, Target: Local, Status Active
- Destination: 0.0.0.0/0, Target: internet-gateway, Status Active

I'm not sure whether my subnet/VPC configuration are incorrect or aws-cdk has a bug.

I've manually tried creating an Application Load Balancer with the public subnets and was able to create is successfully. So I can't say my subnet configs are incorrect.

Comment: It would help if you could provide your VPC's subnet description, too (`aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=vpcId,Values=${VPC_ID}"` - you'll want to remove `SubnetArn`, `SubnetId`, `VpcId` and `OwnerId` from the result before pasting it here).

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while, but i figured it out. 
For my Public Subnet, the attribute: `Auto-assign public IPv4 address` needed to be enabled (set to YES).

But that led to a weird requirement, I have to have the same number of public and private Subnets in all of the supported AZs. I don't understand why. Otherwise i get the error:
 
`Not all subnets in VPC have the same AZs: 
ap-southeast-2a,ap-southeast-2b vs ap-southeast-2a,ap-southeast-2a,ap-southeast-2a,ap-southeast-2a,ap-southeast-2b,ap-southeast-2b,ap-southeast-2b,ap-southeast-2b,ap-southeast-2c,ap-southeast-2c,ap-southeast-2c`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to import and control how your subnets are categorized is to use `ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes`:

```ts
// Import existing VPC
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, 'Vpc', {
  vpcId: 'vpc-xxxxxx',
  availabilityZones: ['eu-west-1a', 'eu-west-1b', 'eu-west-1c'],
  publicSubnetIds: ['subnet-xxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxx'],
  privateSubnetIds: ['subnet-xxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxx'],
});
```

Subnet order and length matters and must match availability zones.

Comment: i mentioned in my description that using fromVPCAttributes i was getting the error "Cannot read property 'selectSubnets' of undefined".

Comment: How would the code look if all your private subnets are in 'eu-west-1a' and all the public ones in 'eu-west-1b'?